# Octopus doesn't replace parameters

Tags: powerbi, octopus-deploy

I have custom step in Octopus.
I set Test parameter on step level, it depend on release variable and is for example `#{Path to package}`.

Step template runs this code:

```
$package = $OctopusParameters['Test']
$cmd = "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe`" -verb:sync -source:package=`"$package`"

Write-Host $cmd
cmd.exe /c $cmd
```

My problem is that variable is not replaced, when `cmd.exe` is called. I get

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="#{Path to package}"
```

However, `#{Path to package}` is replaced, when Write-Host is called:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="c:\realPathToPackage\fromReleaseVariables"
```

How to force replacement before calling `cmd.exe`?

Comment: could you share the complete json for your step template so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: Also, why did you use a parameter name with spaces in it?